# enable permit drawing over message in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am testing my react native application on Pixel 2 API Q. I successfully tested it on iPhone emulator, but when I open the pixel emulator. I keep getting this error. I try to google this error and everyone is saying to go to settings and apps. I don't see any apps in the settings. Below is the screen shot of the error and the settings that I am seeing on this emulator:

[image]

[image]